# Activar extensión php-curl en Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, php7, amp

Tengo un servidor con Ubuntu 18.04 y estoy instalando **AMP** para Wordpress, para eso me solicita activar la extensión **Curl**, de momento ya la he instalado usando el siguiente código:

```html
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
```

ya que tengo corriendo **php 7.2** en mi servidor:
acá dejo una captura

[image: php7.2]

y ya he reiniciado **apache** pero me sigue apareciendo este mensaje en **Wordpress**

[image: Mensaje de error en wordpress]

Pero ahora no se cómo solucionarlo, si me pueden ayudar con esto se los agradecería

Adicional a eso ya descomente la linea de **extension=curl** en mi archivo **php.ini**

Comment: ya editaste tu archivo **php.ini** descomentando la línea que corresponde a CURL?

Comment: @PakLei Si es correcto ya le quite el punto y coma que tenia esa linea esta en la ruta /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini